# How to add the border to Jquery Modal Dialog

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside that div  i have an image which says "Searching .." Now for this modal How to apply the border

```
<div id="waiting-dialog" title="Waiting" style="display:none">
<img src="myimage.gif" border="0" align="middle" hspace="20" vspace="5"/> 
Retrieving all the required information based on your selection.This may take a few moments. Please wait...
</div>
```

And for this Modal I am having the image Appearing on Left side and Text not appearing properly .How can I make tthe text to 
appear in neatly manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the text in a separate div inside the "waiting-dialog" div only, then use the use style float:left for that new div and image. Now you can play around the new div position with paddings, margins and fonts etc to make it neat. see the below sample code.

```
<div id="waiting-dialog" title="Waiting">
<img src="myimage.gif" border="0" align="middle" hspace="20" vspace="5" style=" float:left;"/> 
<div style=" float:left; padding: 5px;"> Retrieving all the required information based on your selection.This may take a few moments. Please wait...</div>
</div>
```